# How to customize keyboard using file xib in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xib, uikeyboard

I want to customize a keyboard in iphone by designing in nib file. How can I call it to use ?

Answer (score 0):

As per [Apple's submission guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html)

- 2.5 Apps that use non-public APIs will be rejected
- 2.6 Apps that read or write data outside its designated container area will be rejected

There are no public APIs to add an additional keyboard

Refer [custom keyboard](http://www.neoos.ch/blog/37-uikeyboardtypenumberpad-and-the-missing-return-key) link for sample.

---

After designing a view u can launch customize keyboard

If u are using  **UITextField** then its delegate are:

Show customize keyboard in below method by resigning textField firstResponder:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField;
```

Hide customize keyboard in below method:

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField;
```

---

If u have **UITextView** then its delegate given below:

Show customize keyboard in below method by resigning textView firstResponder:

```
- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView;
```

Hide customize keyboard in below method:

```
- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView;
```

Comment: You can build your own keyboard (as some calculator apps do) in xib though. But you  have to do the complete handling yourself.